# PostgreSQL : syntax error at or near "," . Is anything wrong here?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

I saw many stackoverflow questions but nothing solved my problem.

```
update employee,works,department set employee.points = employee.points + department.points where employee.ID = works.ID && works.dep_id = department.dep_id && department.title = 'Development';
```

I'm getting this error.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: update employee,works,department set employee.points = employee.p...
```

Can anybody know why?

Comment: You are trying to update employee table only but you wrote 
employee,works,department will not work. Correct syntax would be update employee set employee.points = employee.points + department.points from empoyee join department on ......... In from clause you need to use join all three tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres -- clearly -- does not support this syntax.  You intend something like:

```
update employee e
    set d.points = e.points + d.points
    from works w join
         department d
         on w.dep_id = d.dep_id 
    where e.ID = w.ID and
          d.title = 'Development';
```